# React - componentWillReceiveProps condition doesn't render the data in the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a component with `componentWillReceiveProps` live cycle method.
inside the component, I can an action creator.

As far as I understand the `componentWillReceiveProps` renders the component every second.
for that reason I added a condition to activate the component render only when `this.props` does not equal `prevProps`.

for some reason every time the props are updated the `this.props.fetchCourses();` inside the `componentWillReceiveProps` is not rendered.
as well I don't see the console.log result.What points that the block is not p

I am using `fast-deep-equal` library to compare the objects but I am open to suggestions.

my question is why the component does not render when props are updated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import equal from "fast-deep-equal";

import { fetchCourses, deleteCourse } from "../../actions";

class Courses extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCourses();
  }


  componentWillReceiveProps(prevProps) {
    console.log(this.props.courses);
    console.log(prevProps.courses);

    if (!equal(this.props.courses, prevProps.courses)) {
      this.props.fetchCourses();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const prevProps = prevProps => {
      console.log("this.props", this.props.courses.length);
      console.log("prevProps ", prevProps.courses.length);
    };

    const courses = this.props.courses.map(course => {
      return (
        <tr key={course && course.id}>
          <td>
            {course.coursename}- {course && course.id}
          </td>

          <td>{course.coursetype ? "yes" : "no"}</td>

          <td>{course.courseweeklyhours}</td>

          <td>
            <button
              onClick={() => this.props.deleteCourse(course && course.id)}
            >
              הסר
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

    return <tbody>{courses}</tbody>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log("state ", state);

  return {
    courses: state.courses
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchCourses, deleteCourse }
)(Courses);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my suggestion is you really do not want componentWillReciveProps() to trigger the fetch course... 
whenever you do operation like (create, update, delete , etc..) in courses, 
trigger the fetch course action after each functionality.. it will automatically update the redux-store and component(Courses) will update automatically.

```
handleCreateCourse = async (values)=>{

  //logics for create courses and api call
   await createCourse(values);

   //trigger your fetchCourses action here 
   //it will update your other components where you listened courses from redux.
   this.props.fetchCourses();  

}
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I trigger the fetch after the functionality fires? can you please point me to an example?

Comment: I  removed the `componentWillReceiveProps` and its content and added a call to the action after the render open

`this.props.fetchCourses();` I see the component reners onve a second. is it normal?

Comment: i do not know your use case.. based on your code you do not need componentWillReceiveProps...